# How can I cancel a file upload using the jQuery forms plugin

Tags: jquery-forms-plugin, asyncfileupload

I'm using the jQuery Forms plugin to do an asynchronous file upload. Currently, the only way for the user to abort that upload is to press the "Stop" button on their browser, which may cause other javascript and ajax requests to stop as well. I'd like to provide a cancel button, but I haven't found any way to cancel an upload *as it is happening* using the API.

Is there a built-in way, or at least a robust hack I can use, to cancel the upload as it occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ajaxForm` method takes all the same options that jQuery.ajax takes, so it is possible to capture the dummy `xhr` that it produces in a `beforeSend` handler. The `xhr` has an abort method that aborts the file upload:

```
f.ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        cancelBtn.click(xhr.abort);
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Dec 2012 it is possible to access xhr directly:

```
var form = $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({ ... });
var xhr = form.data('jqxhr');
....
$('#cancel').on('click', function(){
    xhr.abort();
});
```

I use it to cancel ajax file upload.

link - https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/221